# Prestashop, Generating invoice(pdf) automatically

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, invoice

So I'm looking for a solution to save invoice automatically into my server folder, when I press view invoice as the generated URL occurs (http://www.example.com/admin11111/index.php?controller=AdminPdf&token="token"&submitAction=generateInvoicePDF&id_order="id").

I also did research on google, but this solution, somehow didnt work for me: https://www.prestash...es-in-a-folder/

From Prestashop Forum I got advice that I should use shell script, but using a shell download like wget or other only gets me html file, because when I download the invoice in Prestashop backoffice.. it takes some time to generate and the download save appears later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this 2 overrides you could accomplish this.

Override PDF.php:

```
class PDF extends PDFCore
{
    public function render($display = true)
    {
        if($this->template == PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE)
            parent::render('F', true);

        return parent::render($display);
    }
}
```

Override PDFGenerator.php:

```
class PDFGenerator extends PDFGeneratorCore
{
    public function render($filename, $display = true)
    {
        if (empty($filename)) {
            throw new PrestaShopException('Missing filename.');
        }

        $this->lastPage();

        if ($display === true) {
            $output = 'D';
        } elseif ($display === false) {
            $output = 'S';
        } elseif ($display == 'D') {
            $output = 'D';
        } elseif ($display == 'S') {
            $output = 'S';
        } elseif ($display == 'F') {
            $output = 'F';
            $filename = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/'.$filename;
        } else {
            $output = 'I';
        }

        return $this->output($filename, $output);
    }
}
```

Remember to choose another folder other than _PS_ROOT_DIR_. This was just for testing. Try `$filename = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/../invoices/'.$filename;` so it's not a public folder (and you must create the folder with the correct permissions.

Comment: So here what I did. I override PDF and PDFGenerator, I put the code at the bottom of the page, where  class 'PDFCore','PDFGeneratorCore extends TCPDF' code block ended. I created directory invoices with permissions of chmod 777 -R.  This is the code path:  $filename = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/invoices/'.$filename;. Still when I'm pressing view invoice, I get an white page with Internal Server Error(looking network debug) and nothing saved

Comment: did you created the override files in the overrides/classes/pdf with the above contents inside the php tags? also the permission should be 775 or 755 (never 777). and after don't forget to delete(or rename) the file cache/class_index.php. you can check the error_log for the error.

Comment: Thank you really much!!! I really appreciate that! I got it working now, but still one thing.. I changed my invoice folder permissions to 775 and I got and error that "TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: /zzz/zzz/example/invoices/#W003200.pdf" and with 777 all is working fine, I wonder why is that happening?

Comment: check the permission of you img/p folder. then use the same. and check the owner of the folder. if you created with root access, you also need to change to the same owner with chown (could be the user, the www-data, httpd,...)

Comment: The saved invoices filenames start with # like(#W003201.pdf), by regular download there's no #, whys that? I'm pretty sure # is not in the $filename

Comment: you can check if the filename has the # (just do a var_dump($filename); exit;) or just try a $filename = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/'.str_replace("#", "", $filename);

Comment: Yeah it was problem with $filename. The PDF.php render override makes invoice:blank(white) when I'm saving invoice in admin panel(view invoice), is there some solution for this? Currently working on in..